# get field value from eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have this relationship on eloquent

```
public function Manufacturer() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ManufacturerModel', 'id')->select('name');
}
```

And this returns correctly the manufacturer name:

```
{"id":1,"serialnumber":"123_1","buydate":"2018-01-26 00:00:00","offservice":null,"deleted":"0","manufacturer":{"name":"HP"}}
```

I want to retrieve the name **not** as `JSON` object but as a `string`

```
{"id":1,"serialnumber":"123_1","buydate":"2018-01-26 00:00:00","offservice":null,"deleted":"0","manufacturer":"HP"}
```

Comment: How could you get the described return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to define the relationship is:

```
public function Manufacturer() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ManufacturerModel', 'id');
}
```

Then you can get the manufacturer name this way:

```
$your_object->manufacturer->name;
```

Or adding a wrapper method:

```
public function ManufacturerName() {
        return $this->manufacturer->name;
}
```

Notice that when you refer to the relationship without parenthesis the query is executed and what you are accessing is the result. If you don't want the entire record to be queried you can do this:

```
public function ManufacturerName() {
        return $this->manufacturer()->select('name')->get()->name;
}
```

By accessing the relationship with parenthesis you are getting the relationship definition and you can modify it before executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly but you can achieve the functionality using a little bit trick of `php`, for example, if you would like to use it in string context as given below:

```
// {{ $someModel->manufacturer }}
echo $someModel->manufacturer; // or echo Manufacturer::find(1);
```

Then you can do it using the `__toString` magic method in `Manufacturer` model as given below:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

In this case, even on `json_encode($manufacturer)` will give you just `name` so why don't you just use `$model->manufacturer->name;`